# phpmyadmin Default transformations for DateFormat does not change date format

Tags: date, phpmyadmin

I am using phpmyadmin 4.8.3 running on Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS with Mysql 14.14 Distrib 5.6.42. I wanted to change the default format yyyy-mm-dd to dd-mm-yyyy. Based on my research I can do this using "Default transformations for DateFormat" setting. However when I set the new "%d-%m-%Y" format in "Default transformations for DateFormat", it does not change the format of my existing date data or new inserted date. It remains with the yyyy-mm-dd. Is this a bug?

[phpmyadmin DateFormat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSsK7.jpg)

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the manual at
[The DATE, DATETIME, and TIMESTAMP Types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html),
the `Y-m-d` format is the only format that date fields use internally.

This is the format you must use when inserting data.

You can retrieve dates in whatever format you want:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date_field, '%d/%m/%Y')
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However according to this link [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22827579/change-the-date-format-in-phpmyadmin] it should work. By the way, if the sql command is like this "SELECT * FROM payment", how do I specify the DATE_FORMAT in that command?

Comment: These are browser transformation on the PHP side which do not affect the MySQL database in any way. The format for the query is "SELECT col1, col2, ... , DATE_FORMAT(date_field, '%d/%m/%Y'), ... FROM payment".